# MYSQL Sorting and delimited

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have a problem in sorting my line numbers.
My codes output like this

```
(801;802;803;804;805;806;807;808-814(1);808-814(2);815;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;840)
```

and its delimiter will loop until 840.

```
Dim sqlline As DataTable = MyDB.ExecCommand("SELECT `Line Number` from `" + cboJob.Text + "` WHERE `Orig Document Begin ID`='" + mData.Rows(z).Item(0).ToString.Trim + "' ORDER BY `Line Number`", "wellsfargo").Tables(0)
                    For q As Integer = 0 To sqlline.Rows.Count - 1
                        If sqlline.Rows.Count <> 0 Then

                            If q = 0 Then
                                lNum = sqlline.Rows(q).Item(0).ToString
                            Else
                                lNum += IIf(dZ.Rows(q).Item(13).ToString <> "", ";" + sqlline.Rows(q).Item(0).ToString, ";")
                            End If
                            'lNum += IIf(sqlline.Rows(q).Item(0).ToString <> "", ";" + sqlline.Rows(q).Item(0).ToString, "")

                        End If
                    Next
```

But I want my output will be like this.

```
(801;802;803;804;805;806;807;815;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;840;808-814(1);808-814(2))
```

so all the line numbers will be at the end.

now.. EDIT
I have this codes for me to put blanks delimiter at the end of the singe line number:

```
  Dim sCont As String = ""
            If dZ.Rows.Count < 40 Then
                Dim iCont As Integer = 40 - dZ.Rows.Count
                For c As Integer = 0 To iCont - 1
                    If c = 0 Then
                        sCont = ";"
                    Else
                        sCont += ";"
                    End If
                Next
                'Loop then Concatinate strings for each field value.
            ElseIf dZ.Rows.Count = 40 Then
                'Loop as is...
            End If

            Dim sVal As String()
            If dZ.Rows.Count < 40 Then
                sVal = (OrgDocbeg + "■" + _
                                OrgDocend + "■" + _
                                BEGDOC + "■" + _
                                ENDDOC + "■" + _
                                LoanNum + "■" + _
                                PCount + "■" + _
                                Path + "■" + _
                                FNum + "■" + _
                                sDate + "■" + _
                                StrConv(LNF, VbStrConv.ProperCase) + "■" + _
                                lNum + sCont + "■" + _
                                sDesc + sCont + "■" + _
                                StrConv(Amount, VbStrConv.ProperCase).Replace("Poc", "POC").Replace(".00.00", "") + sCont + "■" + _
                                sPay.Replace("^", "").Replace(" Of ", " of ").Replace(" And ", " and ").Replace(" And/or", " and/or").Replace(" By ", " by ").Replace(" 2Nd ", " 2nd ").Replace(" 3Rd ", " 3rd ") + sCont + "■" + _
                                sBorrow.Replace("$.00", "$0.00") + sCont + "■" + _
                                sSell + sCont + "■" + _
                                ProsBor + sCont + "■" + _
                                ProSell + sCont).Split("■")

            Else
                sVal = (OrgDocbeg + "■" + _
                                OrgDocend + "■" + _
                                BEGDOC + "■" + _
                                ENDDOC + "■" + _
                                LoanNum + "■" + _
                                PCount + "■" + _
                                Path + "■" + _
                                FNum + "■" + _
                                sDate + "■" + _
                                StrConv(LNF, VbStrConv.ProperCase) + "■" + _
                                lNum + "■" + _
                                sDesc + "■" + _
                                sPay.Replace("^", "").Replace(" Of ", " of ").Replace(" And ", " and ").Replace(" And/or", " and/or").Replace(" By ", " by ").Replace(" 2Nd ", " 2nd ").Replace(" 3Rd ", " 3rd ") + "■" + _
                                StrConv(Amount, VbStrConv.ProperCase).Replace("Poc", "POC").Replace("$.", "$0.") + "■" + _
                                sBorrow.Replace("$.", "$0.") + "■" + _
                                sSell.Replace("$.", "$0.") + "■" + _
                                ProsBor.Replace("$.", "$0.") + "■" + _
                                ProSell.Replace("$.", "$0.")).Split("■")
            End If
```

But my output is wrong:

```
 801;802;803;804;;;;;;;;808 - 817(1);808 - 817(2);808 - 817(3);808 - 817(4);808 - 817(5);808 - 817(6);;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
```

the output should be like this if I have ranges in the line number (must have delimiter until 840)

```
801;802;803;804;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;808 - 817(1);808 - 817(2);808 - 817(3);808 - 817(4);808 - 817(5);808 - 817(6)
```

**but if I dont have ranges** the correct output will be

```
801;802;803;804
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your line codes have fixed length then you can split resultsets based on the length, sort them independently and then combine them with `UNION ALL`:

```
Dim strQuery = "(SELECT `Line Number` FROM `" + cboJob.Text + _ 
"` WHERE LOCATE('-', line) = 0 AND `Orig Document Begin ID`='" + mData.Rows(z).Item(0).ToString.Trim + _
" ORDER BY `Line Number`) " + _ 
"UNION ALL " + _
"(SELECT `Line Number` FROM `" + cboJob.Text + _ 
"` WHERE LOCATE('-', line) > 0 AND `Orig Document Begin ID`='" + mData.Rows(z).Item(0).ToString.Trim + _
" ORDER BY `Line Number`)"

Dim sqlline As DataTable = MyDB.ExecCommand(strQuery, "wellsfargo").Tables(0)
```

Comment: Well, do you have any deterministic rule that allows to distinguish  between normal sequential numbers like `801;802` and those `808-814(1);808-814(2)`? Is a dash `'-'` sign always separates two parts of latter ones?

Comment: no.. 808-814(1) is just range so its only just one line number.
the '-' is not a delimiter..

Comment: That's not what I meant. Is dash sign is always a part of values that you want to be at the end of your result set?

Comment: i just want to put all the ranges at the end..

like this..
801;802;803;804;805;806;807;808;809;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;840;808-814(1);808-814(2)

Comment: but whats happening is 801;802;;;;;;807;808 - 817(1);808 - 817(2);808 - 817(3);808 - 817(4);808 - 817(5);808 - 817(6);;810

Comment: woah !! thanks a lot ! it works..
now all I have to do is to match it to the other fields....

Comment: uhmmm question.. it works in mySQL but when I try it on my program error happen "Cannot find table 0"

Comment: Some spaces were missing. See the edited answer. And just in case you can always output `strQuery` variable and check for syntax and missing spaces etc.

Comment: ok thank you so much... thats my first problem thank you...
now... if I have the ranges like this...
the output should be,801;802;803;804;805;806;807;808;809;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;840;808-814(1);808-814(‌​2) so the delimiter is until 840 then next are the ranges BUT if i dont have the ranges the output will be 801;802;803;804;805;806;807;808;809 no more delimiter for the blanks

Comment: So did it solve your problem? Or there is another one? I didn't quite understand.

Comment: if I have the ranges like this... the output should be,801;802;803;804;805;806;807;808;809;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;840;808-814(1);808-8‌​14(‌​2) so the delimiter is until 840 then next are the ranges BUT if i dont have the ranges the output will be 801;802;803;804;805;806;807;808;809 no more delimiter for the blanks

Comment: It actually worth another question. But nevertheless see the second answer. The idea is to split the original query into two and execute them sequentially based on the information wether you have ranges or not. Hope that helps.

Comment: yes I think... but is it possible that i can put a delimiter if have ranges ? and the delimiter will be put before the ranges?

Comment: It is. You implement that logic in first `For...Next` loop utilizing intHasRanges variable.

Answer (score 0):

As for the problem noted in last comment, one of the ways to solve this is:

1. Figure out whether you have ranges or not using COUNT
2. Retrieve only normal line numbers and populate your string filling gaps in numbers if you have ranges
3. If you have ranges retrieve them and build a string with range numbers
4. Concatenate your strings

Here is partial or even pseudo-code for that:

```
'Retrieve a count of ranges in the resultset
'Replace objConn with your connection variable 
Dim strQuery As String = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS `RangesCount` FROM `" + cboJob.Text + _ 
"` WHERE LOCATE('-', line) > 0 AND `Orig Document Begin ID`='" + mData.Rows(z).Item(0).ToString.Trim + _
" GROUP BY `Line Number`"
Dim cmdQuery As New MySqlCommand(strQuery, objConn)
Dim intHasRanges As Integer = CInt(cmdQuery.ExecuteScalar())

'Retrieve just line numbers without ranges
'
Dim strQuery As String = "SELECT `Line Number` FROM `" + cboJob.Text + _ 
"` WHERE LOCATE('-', line) = 0 AND `Orig Document Begin ID`='" + mData.Rows(z).Item(0).ToString.Trim + _
" ORDER BY `Line Number`"
Dim sqlline As DataTable = MyDB.ExecCommand(strQuery, "wellsfargo").Tables(0)

'Do your For-Next loop here and populate your first part of your string strResult 
'knowing that if intHasRanges > 0 then we have ranges and we need to fill gaps between numbers
Dim strResult As String = ""
For ...
    ...
    strResult = ...
    ...
Next

'Retrieve ranges only if we have them
'
If intHasRanges > 0 Then
    Dim strQuery As String = "SELECT `Line Number` FROM `" + cboJob.Text + _ 
    "` WHERE LOCATE('-', line) > 0 AND `Orig Document Begin ID`='" + mData.Rows(z).Item(0).ToString.Trim + _
    " ORDER BY `Line Number`"
    Dim sqlline As DataTable = MyDB.ExecCommand(strQuery, "wellsfargo").Tables(0)

    'Do your For-Next loop to populate strRanges
    '
    Dim strRanges As String = ""
    For ...
        strRanges = ...
    Next

    If srtRange.Length > 0 Then
        strResult = strResult + strRanges
    End If
End If

'Do whatever you need to do with that string
```